# Dockerfile: Does it matter how I clean my build?

Tags: c++, docker, dockerfile

Is there a difference (when it comes to image size) between

```
RUN make && make clean
```

and

```
RUN make
RUN make clean
```

Not sure how Docker works, but will the latter create an unnecessary layer?

Comment: A layer is created for each RUN block. Not only image size may get bigger, it may also slow down build considerably. In my practice docker is painfully slow when it comes to image operations and is always a primary bottleneck during build process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RUN make clean` as a separate step will never make your image smaller than skipping it entirely.  If you're going to run it, run it in the same `RUN` command as the build.

More generally, each `RUN` command creates a new Docker image layer.  Creating the layer in itself isn't expensive, but the resulting image is all of the old layers unmodified, *plus* the results of this step.  In your case that translates to the entire build tree, *plus* a record that the object files should be deleted.

If you `RUN make && make clean` in a single step, then the layer isn't created until the entire shell command completes, so the intermediate state isn't persisted.

(Also consider Docker multi-stage builds as a way to build an application from source, but only include the built application in the final image, not any of the build tree or build tools.)